# Highchart Column chart with negative values labels position issue

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

My requirement is to get a chart using hi-chart as below.

[image]

I have tried all types of column charts.This is something that I found.

[Column chart Negetive](http://jsfiddle.net/9dWgL/)

Tried to use offset but the labels overlap and offset needs to be changed according to data and screen which is again a challenge.

[use offset](http://jsfiddle.net/NKXRk/29/)

code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            height: 200,
            spacingBottom: 15,
            spacingTop: 20,
            spacingLeft: 5,
            spacingRight: 15,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#ddd'
        },

        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        legend: {
            padding: 0,
            margin: 5
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    crop: false,
                    overflow: 'none'
                }
            }
        },
        colors: ['#4572A7', '#AA4643', '#89A54E', '#80699B', '#3D96AE', '#DB843D', '#92A8CD', '#A47D7C', '#B5CA92'],
        loading: {
            labelStyle: {
                top: '35%',
                fontSize: "2em"
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["7/12", "7/13", "7/14", "7/15", "7/16", "7/17", "7/18"],
            offset:-58

        },
        series: [{
            "name": "Odometer",
            "data": [{
                "y": -94.98
            }, {
                "y": 182.96
            }, {
                "y": 160.97
            }, {
                "y": -18.00
            }, {
                "y": 117.97
            }, {
                "y": 6.00
            }, {
                "y": 127.97
            }]
        }]


    });
});
```

any other way i could approach this problem.

Comment: In the first example there is no x-axis, so do you want to hide it? Or display it below the most negative bar?

Comment: You can disable xAxis labels and then use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) to add labels in custom places like you need.